# Need to replace """ with "" for all records in a csv file using a batch file

Tags: csv, batch-file

I need to replace `"""` with `""` in a csv file for any line in the file which contains these string of characters.

Basically, I need this:

```
"Pipe 60"""
```

To look like this:

```
"Pipe 60""
```

This field is a key field that is needed to import data back in to the Inventory Software I'm using.  When I remove the extra quote in notepad, it imports without issue.  The problem is, there are several key fields like this, and it would be time consuming to edit each field through notepad.

I tried the code below I found on a previous post but the output file displays no data:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

(for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (a.csv) do if not "%%f"=="" (
        set "line=%%f"
        set "line=!line"""=""!"
        echo(!line!
)) > b.csv

endlocal
```

Here's an example of my csv file:

```
000,,PipeSm,,1
000,,"Pipe 60""",,1
000,,PipeMd,,1
```

I don't use batch files that often so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: _For clarity:_ A self-escaped double quote in a double quoted field value. Done for CSV parsers to fetch a field value. They then would un-escape `""` to a single double quote (and remove the surrounding double quotes)..Maybe replace `""` with `”` U+201D - or `″` U+2033

Comment: @Gerhard Thank you for pointing that out to me  Gerhard. I forgot to strip that comma out of my code

Comment: As already mentioned, if you remove those extra doublequotes, your CV would no longer be capable of being parsed as a CSV. If the file could one day be imported or parsed as a CSV, you may get away with removing all the doublequotes surrounding each field then replace all instances of `""` with `"`. You certainly shouldn't consider modifying the, _double prime marks_ in favor of an _invalid_ character, even if you could guarantee the code page/character set.

Comment: Just to confirm, the example CSV, file you've now added is 100% correct, that particular field was doublequoted to protect the inch symbol. If you remove them, your file may no longer be parsed correctly. The choice is yours.

Comment: @Compo I'm able to edit it in notepad, and it imports in to my Inventory software with no issues.  Is notepad really the only way I can edit this line without issue?  (I'm a batch file novice)

Comment: I agree with the others. `"Pipe 60"""` is absolutely right. Please read Wikipedia article about [comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_separated_values) (CSV) format. Not right is using the double quotation mark character as unit character for inches, except in ASCII files or ANSI encoded files with a code page not supporting the right character. The correct unit character for inches is the [double prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_(symbol)) symbol if the character encoding of the file supports this symbol.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I tried it but to be quite honest, I don't know if I did it right because even though I now have data in the new csv file, it didn't resolve the issue. Below is what my code looks like now:

'@echo off'
'    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion'
'    (for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (a.csv) do echo %%~i) > b.csv'
'    endlocal'

Comment: I suggest using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) for this task as Windows command processor is designed for running commands and executables, but not for file modification tasks. I suggest using as search string `"([0-9])\x22\x22"` and as replace string `"$1\x22"` or in case of CSV file is UTF-16 encoded `"$1\x{2033}"`.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Are you referring to the csv string?  I edited my original post to show the csv contents.

Comment: Your missing the `:` in your string replacement. It should be `set "line=!line:"""=""!"`

Comment: @dbenham thank you for noting that but even after I added the colon, it still gave me blank data.  Gerhard Barnard actually resolved my issue with the answer below.

Comment: Your code worked for me after I added the missing colon. The missing colon would explain empty output because a variable named `line"""=""` does not exist.

Comment: @dbenham You are absolutely right!  I must've put the colon in the wrong part of the variable when you mentioned it to me last time.  It does work!  Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it as is:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (a.csv) do (
        set "line=%%f"
        echo(!line:"""=""!
 )
)> b.csv
```

**EDIT**
As per your comment, give this a go.. still assuming the file is called `a.csv` also note that this will write the changes back to the original file, so please test it on dummy files first.

```
@echo off
set "_infile=C:\Users\jdoe\Desktop\Removing Quotes\ImportFolder\a.csv"
for /f "tokens=2* delims=]" %%f in ('type "%_infile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "%_infile%"') do (
       set "line=%%f"
       setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
       set "line=!line:"""=""!"
       echo(!line!
       endlocal
)>>"%_infile%"
```

Comment: I'm trying to specify the source file and destination file via a variable and it doesn't seem to be identifying either.  I've done this before with another batch file and it seemed to work.  Can you tell me if there's anything I'm doing wrong?
'SET "FileName=Physical.csv"'
'SET "ImportFolder=C:\Users\jdoe\Desktop\Removing Quotes\ImportFolder"'
'SET "TempFolder=C:\Users\jdoe\Desktop\Removing Quotes\TempFolder"'
'REM This replaces a.csv'
'SET "ImportFile=%ImportFolder%\%FileName%"'
'REM This replaces b.csv'
'SET "TempFile=%TempFolder%\%FileName%"'

Comment: Are you planning to write back to the original file?

Comment: Yes, i am.  The import program I use on the Inventory Software is pointing to the Import folder.  An end user needs to be able to drop in that a.csv file in to that folder.  This batch file will run prior to the import being done.  So the plan was to keep the file name the same, but output to a different folder, and then move it back to it's original location, overwriting the original file.

Comment: Ok. So you want to retain a.csv in the import folder but with the removal of the additional quotes?

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work.  Also, every time I run this, it creates a "Removing" ghost file on my desktop.

Comment: You're a genius!  I really appreciate it.